# SQL Query Builder and Validation in Java

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, builder

I am creating a user interface for users to construct queries visually (similar to MS Access but without the bells and whistles). The User Interface is developed in Java, JavaScript, JQuery and Struts. Once the query is constructed based on user selection of tables, fields, conditions and values the query should be validated before it hits the database. Currently the target database for the query to execute is MySQL but it could vary such as Oracle or Postgres. Could you kindly let me know of any libraries that could validate the queries for different databases or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a layer of abstraction like a ORM may help you. A widely know ORM is [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org).

Comment: Thanks, In hibernate we should know the table structure and no of columns so that can create persistence class and use it before running application. My dynamic requirement is without knowing table structure,ie., without knowing persistence class variables how can i dynamically change configuration for multuple databases?

Comment: Any alternatives for dynamic requirement without knowing table structure?